# Replacing the 1st regex-match group instead of the 0th

Tags: regex, kotlin

I was expecting this

```
val string = "hello   , world"
val regex = Regex("""(\s+)[,]""")

println(string.replace(regex, ""))
```

to result in this:

```
hello, world
```

Instead, it prints this:

```
hello world
```

I see that the `replace` function cares about the whole match. Is there a way to replace only the 1st group instead of the 0th one?

Comment: Capturing a part of the text helps *keep* it using backrefrences in the replacement pattern. What you need to remove should not be captured. You could use `Regex("""\s+(,)""")` and then `.replace(regex, "$1")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the comma in the replacement:

```
val string = "hello   , world"
val regex = Regex("""(\s+)[,]""")

println(string.replace(regex, ","))
```

Or, if kotlin supports lookahead:

```
val string = "hello   , world"
val regex = Regex("""\s+(?=,)""")

println(string.replace(regex, ""))
```

Comment: Yes, Kotlin supports lookaheads

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the match range of the regular expression by using the groups property of MatchGroupCollection and then using the range as a parameter for String.removeRange method:

```
val string = "hello   , world"
val regex = Regex("""(\s+)[,]""")
val result = string.removeRange(regex.find(string)!!.groups[1]!!.range)
```

Comment: While this can be achieved, this does not "replace" a group, but just remove it